# Как перезаписать многомерный массив без определенного значения?

Tags: php

Есть многомерный массив типа

```
array(2) { ["sas kamera , Mp"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(18) "12 p + 12 p + 12 p" [1]=> string(11) "12 p + 12 p" [2]=> string(4) "12 p" } ["Buraxl tarixi"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(18) "2019, 20 sentyabr " [1]=> string(13) "2016, 31 mart" [2]=> string(16) "2020, 23 oktyabr" } }
```

Нужно перезаписать его но без определенного значения, например без значения "12 p + 12 p + 12 p" по ключу "sas kamera , Mp" через foreach или for.

```
        for ($i=0; $i < count($session); $i++) { 
            $value = $session[$i];
            if ($_POST['value'] != $value) {
                $newarray[count($newarray)] = $session[$i];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Сформулируйте нормально вопрос и поправьте код (массив невалидный)!

Comment: Массив валидный, это распечатка var_dump, для полной ясности, вопрос заключался в том, что бы перезаписать многомерный массив, без определенного значения по ключу.

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach ($session as $key => &$value) {

            if ($key == $_POST['name']) {

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++) { 
                    $value_i = $value[$i];
                    if ($value_i != $_POST['value']) {
                        $newarray[count($newarray)] = $value[$i];
                    };
                }
                $value = $newarray;
                if ($value == NULL) {
                    unset($session[$key]);
                }
            };              

        }
```

Comment: $_POST['name'] - получаемый ключ, $_POST['value'] - значение которое надо удалить, т.е перезаписать массив без этого значения, делаем через for, далее проверяем или пустой массив, если да то удаляем его из основного вместе с ключом, что бы не мешался, по выходу получает чистый многомерный массив. Подходит для checkbox с работой через ajax при включении и выключении checkbox.